# To check if an element already exists in the array and then if it does exist, delete it

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, session

The parameter is taken from the url like this `file.php?item=xyz`
I have an array `$_SESSION['arr']`.

Now I want to check if `xyz` is present in `$_SESSION['arr']` and delete it if it is present.

In the end I send my result to the calling JQuery function as
           `echo json_encode($_SESSION['arr']);`

EDIT: And if the element is not present, add it to the array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `in_array()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you :)

```
foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $value)
{
 //converting to lowercase
 $value= strtolower($value)
 if($value == "xyz")
 {
   //removing $value from $_SESSION['arr'] 
   unset($_SESSION['arr'][$value]);
 }
 else
 {
  //adding value to array
  array_push($_SESSION['arr'], "xzy");
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey this works! Thanks, could you also tell how to add a element if it is not already present in the array. I have mentioned in the EDIT section of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
if(isset($_GET['item']) && $_GET['item'] == "xyz")
{
  if(in_array($_GET['item'],$_SESSION['arr']))
  {
     //Delete it
  }
}
```

Comment: Please give your feedback on answers. @Anusha

Comment: I had tried `in_array()` method before, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Please explain in detail your issue where its not working for u because i am dam sure its correct as per your query. @Anusha

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['item']))
{
 if(in_array($_GET['item'],$_SESSION['arr']))
  { 
   $pos = array_search($_GET['item'], $_SESSION['arr']);
   unset($_SESSION['arr'][$pos]);// deletes 
  }
```

not tested but logic like this. hope helps :)